# Filtering options in Webix combo/richselect

Tags: javascript, user-interface, drop-down-menu, combobox, webix

I want to set the options in the second combo depending on the selected value (or some group ID) in the previous one (richselect control):

```
rows:[
    { 
      view:"richselect", label:"Country",             
      id:'rich_1', value:1,
      options:countries, 
      on:{onChange:function(newv){
        $$("combo_1").getList().filter( function(obj){                  
          if (obj.country == newv) console.log(obj.value);
          return obj.country == newv;
        });
      }}
    },
    { 
      view:"combo", id:"combo_1", label:"Name",   
      options:cities              
    }
]
```

**[Snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/ad1f196c)**

The filtering function works, but I've found that the options are refreshing when showing. I didn't found an event like `onBeforeShow` for the combo, so the question - is there a way to filter these options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combo uses filtering itself, for adjusting result, which disables the result of your custom filtering logic.

Please check the next snippet http://webix.com/snippet/da3923b5
It uses a bit more complex logic, here we have an intermediate data collection.

var cDC = new webix.DataCollection({ data: cities });

Now, the first combo filters the collection, and each time as collection changes, the second combo will reload data from the collection.

```
webix.ui({
  rows:[
    { 
      view:"richselect", label:"Country",             
      id:'rich_1', value:0,
      options:countries, 
      on:{
        onChange:function(newv){
          cDC.filter( function(obj){                  
            if (obj.country == newv) console.log(obj.value);
            return obj.country == newv;
          });
        }
      }
    },
    { 
      view:"combo", id:"combo_1", label:"City",   
      options:{ data: cDC }
    }
  ]
});
```

And if you are interested, combo has onBeforeShow event handler as well

```
{ 
  view:"combo", id:"combo_1", label:"City",   
  options:{ 
    data: cDC, 
    on:{ onBeforeShow:function(){ webix.message("show"); }}
   }
}
```